# Excel VBA: (Mac-specific) Calling Application object causes other workbooks to un-minimize

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a workbook that includes 12 modules, plus over 25 worksheets with sheet-specific macros. On each one I include the line:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

with the corresponding "= True" at the end of the code.

This is great for performance, but what I've noticed is if I click anywhere in my workbook, it will cause any other Excel workbook I am using to un-minimize (zoom up from the dock) if it is currently minimized. It does not cause non-active windows to become active.

This is not a minor issue, as it is likely that anyone at my organization who is using this workbook will simultaneously be working on 2-3 other Excel documents at the same time, most of which will be minimized to save screen space.

Is there a way to prevent the Application object from unminimizing minimized windows?

Comment: If you click anywhere in Workbook X, *after* the macros run, minimized Workbooks Y and Z maximize/come to focus?

Comment: You might try putting "stops" in your various modules so that you can pinpoint the problem.  If you know what's causing it, you could at the very least, use lines such as ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized to send it back to minimized

Comment: @BruceWayne It's at the point when the Application object is called, which is right at the beginning of the macro (Application.ScreenUpdating = False). I pinpointed this by removing/commenting out that line and counterpart at the end of the script, and the windows stayed minimized.